# Detect query type( query, mutation, subscription) in graphql-java

Tags: java, graphql-java

Is there a way to detect the query type `query` , `mutation` or `subscription` , preferably without executing the query.

For example:

```
ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput
    .newExecutionInput()
    .query("subscription Test{test}")
    .build();
```

Is it possible to detect that this is a subscription request? `subscription Test{test}` without executing the query?

Something like `executionInput.isSubscription()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ParseAndValidate` to parse the `ExecutionInput` :

```java
ParseAndValidateResult parseResult = ParseAndValidate.parse(executionInput);
        parseResult.getDocument().getDefinitionsOfType(OperationDefinition.class)
        .forEach(d->{
            System.out.println(d.getOperation());
        });
```

The idea is to get the list of the `OperationDefinition` from `Document` (i.e query parsing result) and get its `Operation` type (an enum which has value `QUERY`,`MUTATION`,`SUBSCRIPTION`) from `OperationDefinition`.

<sub>*P.S. I test with graphql-java v17*</sub>